# Difference between linking libfdisk.a directly and through -lfdisk

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, c-libraries

I've made program, which formats storage devices. However, when I've created library (for python GUI) based on this program it starts to show the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: fdisk/libfdisk.a(la-label.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

libfdisk.a, which I use, has been built from source `util-linux-2.35`.
And when `-lfdisk` is used instead of `libfdisk.a`, it compiles with no errors.

Compiles with errors:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ... -o package.name ... libfdisk.a
```

Compiles correctly:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ... -o package.name ... -lfdisk
```

What the difference between these 2 ways?

But there is another, optional, question about fdisk. When I compile my program (not library) with `-lfdisk`, program can not create 2 partitions due to error 28 (returns from fdisk_add_partition(...)).
I'll share the code if it needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-lfdisk` the linker is asked to figure out which library file exactly to use.

The usual linkers on Linux will prefix `lib` and then search for files with `.so` or `.a` ending in the library path, which because you didn't specify any, will be the system library path (probably `/usr/lib/` or similar). If a `.so` is found, it will be preferred for linking if a static link wasn't requested.

Your other method will explicitly add in the file named `libfdisk.a` in the current directory. That is a static library, not a shared one, and if you try to build a shared library from it, then you need to have compiled `libfdisk.a` with `-fPIC` or if you try to build a PIE executable at least with `-fPIE`. If you are trying to build a non-PIE executable, then neither flag is required. GCC may be configured to build PIE by default (as a hardening measure).

So you are probably linking two completely different files.